# Skillbar not loading Error message: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: animate.css

I am trying to animate a 'Skillbar' using HTML, CSS, JS, and animate.css.  I am getting the error:

> Error feedback: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

I am using a grid system rather than bootstrap

```js
var skillBarTopPos = jQuery('.skillbar').position().top; 
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrolled_val = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf(); 
    if(scrolled_val>skillBarTopPos-250) 
        startAnimation();
});
function startAnimation(){ 
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({ 
            width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
        },6000);
    });
};
```

Comment: Apologies but it wouldn't allow me to add the full code

Comment: var skillBarTopPos = jQuery('.skillbar').position().top;
  jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrolled_val = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
    if(scrolled_val>skillBarTopPos-250) startAnimation();
  });

  function startAnimation(){
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
      jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
        width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
      },6000);
    });
  };

Comment: Could you please share the accompanying HTML for this JavaScript?